# Android Advance WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using advance `Webview` for uploading multiple images in my application while uploading image in `Webview`, `file-chooser` option is not appeared. I need to upload images from Camera capture. Please give the solution.

`XML` code :-

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView>
```

`Android` Code :-

```
mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.setListener(this, this);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    mWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/SatanPandeya/file_chooser_webview  This may help.

Comment: Consider asking for permissions using Java/Kotlin (fro Oreo and above)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out: [Github](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp)
I used it my self and it worked. 
Don't forget to add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have any more question just ask. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I have already added above permissions in my AndroidManifest file.

Comment: I am using "im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView" because I have to upload multiple images using gallery with file chooser option not displaying. In simple webview multiple image selection issue but it is giving option for file chooser.

Comment: If he isn't showing it that isn't it possible. Did you see examples with that code where you can show from gallery?